# Translate demo failed to translate Chinese, maybe the encode failure?

Tags: c++

Recently, I implemented a online translate demo, yes, it worked well when a tried to translate a English word to Chinese, but unfortunately, it's failed to translate a Chinese word to English.

I think maybe this issue was caused by the encode of the Chinese, I tried to print the url, and copy them to IE, the result IE returned is right.

The code is as follows:

```
/*
Filename: translate.cc
Author: BerlinSun
*/
#include <iostream>
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "json/json.h"

using namespace std;

void usage()
{
    cout << "Usage: translate word_you_want_to_translate" << endl;
}

int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *writerData)
{
    if (writerData == NULL)
        return 0;
    int len = size*nmemb;
    writerData->append(data, len); 
    return len;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        usage();
        exit(0);
    }
    string buffer;
    string translate_url = "http://fanyi.youdao.com/openapi.do?keyfrom=xxxxxx&key=xxxxxx&type=data&doctype=json&version=1.1&q=";
    translate_url += argv[1];
    CURL * curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, translate_url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    if (buffer.empty())
    {
        cout << "The server return NULL!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;
    bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse(buffer, root);

    if (!parsingSuccessful)
    {
        cout << "Failed to parse the data!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    const Json::Value basic = root["basic"];
    const Json::Value phonetic = basic["phonetic"];
    const Json::Value explains = basic["explains"];
    cout << "Provided by Youdao dictionary!" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << argv[1] << "\t英[" << phonetic.asString()  << "]" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < explains.size(); ++i)
        cout << explains[i].asString() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What OS? Linux? How is argv[1] encoded? is it UTF8? or maybe it is UCS4... You need to encode the character in the encoding that the website expects. On linux, the encoding of the character that you receive in your application depends on the configuration of the console.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding

Comment: Linux, for example, I ran the demo via: ./translate "futures", it was worked well, but if I ran it via:./translate "期货", the result the demo returned would be null, but if I just use the url with "期货", the IE will return the right result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue have been resolved by myself, I checked the manaul of the libcurl and found that this is a function can be used to encode the url:

```
char *curl_easy_escape( CURL * curl , char * url , int length );
```

and I modified my source to judge the argv[1], if argv[1] is non-assic, then I would use this function converted.

Thank you all the same.